# sending error message laravel required inputs

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.1

so i wanted to make validation to my register form so i made all my inputs required so i can test my validation that it works or not, so this is what i used in my controller

```
$Message = [
        'required' => 'This input is required',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'UserName' => 'required',
        'Phone' => 'required',
        'SSN' => 'required',
        'SDT' => 'required',
        'Country' => 'required',
        'InsuranceAmount' => 'required',
        'City' => 'required',
        'Location' => 'required'
    ], $Message);

    if ($validator->fails()) {


        return redirect('/admin/users/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $user = new User;
    $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->email = Input::get('email');
    $user->password = bcrypt(Input::get('password'));
    $user->UserName = input::get('UserName');
    $user->Phone = input::get('Phone');
    $user->SSN = input::get('SSN');
    $user->SDT = input::get('SDT');
    $user->Country = input::get('Country');
    $user->City = input::get('City');
    $user->Location = input::get('Location');
    $user->save();
    return Redirect::to('/admin/users')->with('message', 'User Created');
```

Now if theres no errors it works fine and redirect to user list, but if a input is empty it will just redirect to the creation page whict is what i wanted but the problem is it won't send the error message with the redirect i tried dd the validator and it has all the messages fine heres my view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ Route('userstore') }}">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">الاسم</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('UserName') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">اسم المستخدم</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="UserName" value="{{ old('UserName') }}">
                            @if ($errors->has('UserName'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('UserName') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('Phone') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">رقم الجوال</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Phone" value="{{old('Phone')}}">
                            @if ($errors->has('Phone'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('Phone') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('SSN') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">الرقم الوطني</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SSN" value="{{old('SSN')}}">
                            @if ($errors->has('SSN'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('SSN') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('SDT') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">نوع الوثيقة</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SDT" value="{{old('SDT')}}">
                            @if ($errors->has('SDT'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('SDT') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('Country') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">الدولة</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select class="form-control" name="Country">

                                <option>الاردن</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">المدينة</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <select class="form-control" name="City" >
                              <option>عمان</option>
                          </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('Location') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">اسم الشارع</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Location" value="{{old('Location')}}">
                            @if ($errors->has('Location'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('Location') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }} ltr-input">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">البريد الإلكتروني</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }} ltr-input">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">كلمة المرور</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }} ltr-input">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">تأكيد كلمة المرور</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i> تسجيل
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and btw this is laravel 5.1

Comment: make sure that `admin/users/create` is not also performing a redirect otherwise the flash messages will be lost

Comment: @Snapey what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that flashed data (and old data) only exists for one request. So if you redirect and then redirect again, the old form data will be lost

Comment: @Snapey NVM i fixed it by upgrading the project to laravel 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem by upgrading my project from laravel 5.1 to 5.5